# Two divs click event works only on one div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery and ajax to create a drawer (#DrawerContainer) and load content into it if I click a thumbnail in a gallery. My function is almost finished but I want to be able to close that drawer if I click again the opening button (now #current).

Here is a jsfiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/RF6df/54/
The drawer element appears if you click a square/thumbnail, it's the blueish rectangle.
The current thumbnail is turned green.

I added a button in my drawer (not visible in the jsfiddle) to close it. I use this part of code for this purpose and it's working like a charm.

```
      // Close the drawer
        $(".CloseDrawer").click(function() {
            $('#DrawerContainer').slideUp()
                setTimeout(function(){ // then remove it...
                    $('#DrawerContainer').remove();
                }, 300); // after 500ms.
            return false;
        });
```

Now I need my `#current` div to be able to close `#DrawerContainer` the same way `.CloseDrawer` does in the code above. 
Unfortunately adding a second trigger like this `$("#current,.CloseDrawer").click(function()` to my function isn't working... When clicking my "current" thumbnail, it just reopen the drawer instead of closing it...

How can I modify my code to close my #DrawerContainer with the "current" thumbnail?

Please keep in mind that I'm learning jquery, so if you can comment it could be of a great help. And please do not modify my markup or css, since everything works beside the closing part.

Comment: Can you link to the website you have this implemented in, or add the button to the jsfiddle, please?

Comment: I'm working locally but the squares are the buttons on jsfiddle.

Comment: What I see is that the code inside `$("#current,.CloseDrawer").click(function() { ... });` doesn't run at all. Add an `alert()` and see for yourself.

Comment: you're right, I'm sure it's because it's loaded on `.ajaxSuccess`. I don't know how to make ajax work on jsfiddle but my .CloseDrawer button works locally.

Comment: [This edit](http://jsfiddle.net/RF6df/41/) looks good enough for me, maybe try working off of it?

Comment: There might be something not clear in my post because it's not working better than my code and everyone here wants to change my css... Maybe I'll update it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you can use "toggle()" function which does exactly the same (i.e, toggle visiblity).

```
$('#DrawerContainer').toggle();
```

**EDIT:**
Updated the script to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});

    $('#portfolio-list>div:not(#DrawerContainer)').click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("id") != "current")
        {
    // modify hash for sharing purpose (remove the first part of the href)
    var pathname = $(this).find('a')[0].href.split('/'),
            l = pathname.length;
        pathname = pathname[l-1] || pathname[l-2];
        window.location.hash = "#!" + pathname;

    $('#current').removeAttr('id');
    $(this).attr('id', 'current');

    // find first item in next row
    var LastInRow = -1;
    var top = $(this).offset().top;
    if ($(this).next().length == 0 || $(this).next().offset().top != top) {
        LastInRow = $(this);
    }
    else {
        $(this).nextAll().each(function() {
            if ($(this).offset().top != top) {
                return false; // == break from .each()            
            }
            LastInRow = $(this);
        });
    }
    if (LastInRow === -1) {
        LastInRow = $(this).parent().children().last();
    }

    // Ajout du drawer
    var post_link = $(this).find('.mosaic-backdrop').attr("href");
        $('#DrawerContainer').remove(); // remove existing, if any
        $('<div/>').attr('id', 'DrawerContainer').css({display: 'none'}).data('citem', this).html("loading...").load(post_link + " #container > * ").insertAfter(LastInRow).slideDown(300);
        return false; // stops the browser when content is loaded
    }
    else {
          $('#DrawerContainer').slideUp(300);   
         $(this).removeAttr("id");
    }

   });

    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {

        Cufon('h1'); //refresh cufon

        // Toggle/close the drawer
        $("#current,.CloseDrawer").click(function() {
            $('#DrawerContainer').slideToggle()
                setTimeout(function(){ // then remove it...
                    $('#DrawerContainer').remove();
                }, 300); // after 500ms.
            return false;
        });

    });

    //updated Ene's version
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if ( hash.length > 0 ) {
        hash = hash.replace('#!' , '' , hash );
        $('a[href$="'+hash+'/"]').trigger('click');
    }

});
```

Also, updated it here: [Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RF6df/32/)

**EDIT -2:** [Updated Link](http://jsfiddle.net/RF6df/55/)

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Thanks Praveen, you are the closest! I modified a little bit your code otherwise the drawer wasn't opened if we load a specific url. I only have one problem now. I have to click twice to close the drawer, and when it's closed, I can't open it anymore... As I'm learning, I'm having hard time finding where it's coming from... Could you please have a look? http://jsfiddle.net/RF6df/45/

Comment: Updated the answer with new script and provided the link. Hope this solves your problem

Comment: thanks for taking the time, but now I can't even open the drawer. :( Not sure where it's coming from, I'll have a look later. By the way here is my actual code http://jsfiddle.net/RF6df/54/ Still the closing problem, but I suspect jsfiddle doesn't consider ajaxSuccess...